# Restaurar .bak en SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-ce

Buen día a todos, mi duda en si es la siguiente de como restaurar un respaldo de sql server .bak a una base de datos .mdf de sql server compact edition / o en otro caso como ejecutar un script .sql en sql server ce, de antemano gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad no se puede "restaurar" una base de datos de una versión a otra. Pero puede realizar una migración de la información con alguna herramienta externa.
Aquí están los detalles del proceso:

http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2012/02/migrating-databases-between-sql-server.html

http://lh3.ggpht.com/-HKG-sV22gpc/T0rVoh8K7pI/AAAAAAAAAso/QCr5Kh_SXPE/s1600-h/image25.png

Detalla como cargar la herramienta en el SQL y la opción para realizar la migración.

Comment: Entiendo, pero en el  caso de que ya tenga el script .sql hay una manera de que así lo pueda hacer?, Gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: El motor de un SQL compact es muy limitado y probablemente no pueda entender que deba hacer con el script que le estas enviando si viene de una versión estandar.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta.